# jQuery isotope browser window size issues

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I am having a problem with the ISOTope plugin - it is a responsive design so if you have a look at it on the iPad or even better still resize the window so its roughly the size of the ipad screen or make it smaller than that. Refresh the page and the last element in the list with the image beside it you can't see the learn more button unless you resize the window 1px to the right left

The link to the website is here; http://bit.ly/VIuH8e

```
jquery.isotope.min.js
jquery.isotope.run.js
```

The script;

```
$('ul.moreServices').isotope({
    // options
    itemSelector: 'li.one_half',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```

I've tried adding the masonry and setting the column width in the selector but no joy

Anyone have any ideas on how to like relay the items based on the browser window size, full view browser window is fine its only when you resize window and refresh the page it causes issues it's like the ISOTope is cutting off the last element in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this problem - overflow was getting over-written by the plugin so stuck important on the style. Not too keen on using the important on css styles. But hey ho no arguments if it fixes the problem

Comment: You probably saved me a lot of hours here! Thank you for adding the answer!